# How can my RNN get way better results than my ANN

Tags: classification, recurrent-neural-networks, data-preprocessing, binary-classification

So, I'm using the same dataset in both models but my RNN gets a 95% accuracy and my ANN gets 52%.

It is a time series, binary classification problem, and I know that RNN is better than ANN for time series, but I was suspecting that there was some data leak, since 95% is way higher than I expected.

Is it possible that I have a data leak only in my RNN? Or are RNN this much better than ANN for time series?

Comment: What do you mean by "data leak" in this case? Without having almost no info about your dataset, it's not possible to answer this unclear question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_(machine_learning)

lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An RNN has a recursive element to it, as its output is fed back as part of the next input; this provides a kind of memory.

When analysing a time series, values tend to depend on previous values (unless the time series is random), so an RNN is bound to perform better, as it has more context for classification.

An ANN basically just looks at values in isolation, and thus cannot make use of the history of the time series. So I would expect it to perform much worse in this case.